# Does Apple ship debugging symbols for the iPhone Simulator APIs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am a bit of a iPhone/Mac OS newb.
When I look at a backtrace in the debugger and UIKit or other Apple Libraries are on the call stack I can't see their function arguments because of missing debug symbols.

Does Apple Ship debugging symbols for the iPhone Simulator libraries like UIKit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The OS-level components do not ship with debug symbols, nor have those symbols available to you.  On the Mac, the only case I can think of where a special debug version of a framework was made available was for Core Data, but that was more for logging of SQL and other database-related actions.

You can extract a little more information about what's going on in the Simulator using DTrace scripts and custom instruments, which can probe for even private methods and classes.  For example, I created a couple of scripts and a custom instrument [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/DTraceStartup.zip) that logs out every method that is called in the process of starting up an iPhone application in the Simulator.  I describe how that works in [this article](http://www.macresearch.org/tuning-cocoa-applications-using-dtrace-custom-static-probes-and-instruments) on MacResearch.